# Replacing Static Resource (java script) variables run time

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, static-resources

I understand that the static resources (java script) are supposed to be static and loaded only once at run time.
However, I have a requirement to dynamically change the content of a script depending on User context (or mainly data coming from Apex).

Is there a way to change the static resource variables dynamically by passing the data from Apex controller?

I am using Aura components as I need to finally include them on Community.

Comment: I think you should not consider changing something inside js static resource.  By naming it is **static**, not dynamic.  if it is your js code, consider switching to aura service components or extended component with a shared helper.

Comment: Finally , it is not even a piece of code that needs to be executed. Rather a script that needs to be loaded with some variables. I am wondering if the Service components in Aura can help in loading this in page. Or a VF page route may be a better approach to have control over the script dynamic variables?